# Xcode 4 and Branches

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am using Xcode 4.5 and Git for version control. I created a new branch and added some code to it. When I go to Organizer/My Repository and click on switch branch, I can't switch to a branch because I get the following error message :

> Working copy is modified

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to remove the xcuserstate and added it to my .gitignore

```
git rm --cached ProjectFolder.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/myUserName.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
git commit -m "Removed file that shouldn't be tracked"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to commit changes to that branch first before you can switch branches.

Comment: I did that, I noticed that the xcuserstate is the file not committed. How can I add that to the ignore list?

Answer (score -1):

I came across the same problem yesterday, I simply go to the project directory, use these commands, and able to solve the problem.
    git add . and 
    git commit -m "resolved working copy is modified"